# 12.04 losing display settings on startup

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop at work. It seems like every other week when I boot up my computer it loses its display settings. It's to the point where I have to bring up the virtual console (CTRL+ALT+F1) to stop the *lightdm* service, reinstall the NVIDIA driver and reboot. It runs fine every other time... Just once in awhile I have to reinstall the graphics driver.

Doing this doesn't take all that much time (5-8 minutes, tops), but it's annoying that I have to do this every couple weeks.

System information:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Memory: 7.8gb
- Processor: AMD FX 8120 (8 cores) - 64 bit
- Disk: 2TB
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA Quadro FX 1700
- Graphics Driver: NVIDIA Linux x86(64) 310.19 (The most recent version
  is 310.32)

Any idea what could be causing such an issue? Would upgrading to the most recent Linux driver from NVIDIA fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, using the drivers from Nvidia's website is likely to cause more problems than it solves (not the least of which being that it's a PITA to install to begin with).

On my system, there tends to be three Nvidia drivers, in addition to the generic one. An experimental, a stable, and a stable tested. I'd recommend trying one of the others and see if that makes a difference.

Also, keep an eye on updates and see if there's a kernel or Nvidia driver update that corresponds with your issue. Keep notes of what was going on before you shut down before the issues and see if you find any patterns.

Comment: Thanks! A couple times yesterday Ubuntu popped up and said it had a system error, and I reported the error using the prompt. Although, I didn't actually read the report since I didn't notice anything going wrong, I just figured it was most likely an internal program error and it recovered with no other issues.


Next time I comes up, I'll make a note of what caused the error. This has happened before, without Ubuntu losing it's display settings.